# Need help configuring IIS to serve 2.0 web services

Tags: iis

I am attempting to deploy an ASP.NET 2.0 Web service application on an IIS server that currently serves a large .NET 1.0 web application.

I have set up an appropriate virtual directory and have set the ASP.NET version for the virtual directory to 2.0, when I attempt to browse the site in a web-browser, I am prompted for a password. If I set the ASP.NET version down to 1.0, I am not prompted for a password, but obviously receive a full application error.

How can I configure IIS so that I can have the .NET 2.0 version selected without requiring the password prompt?

I have anonymous access enabled and have the "Authenticated Access" set to integrated windows authentication"

I should mention that I have another 2.0 web service application configured on this server the same as this and it is working fine. Any help or suggestions is appreciated...

Thanks.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243852/need-help-configuring-iis-to-serve-20-web-services

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting prompted, then you most likely have a security configuration issue on the VDir.

Couple of things to check -

1. What is your authentication set to - Anonymous or Windows Integrated.
2. If you're set to Anonymous, does the anonymous users group have rights?
3. If you're set to WIA, does the IIS_WPG have rights?
4. What's your application Pool running as?  If its a local account or domain account, have you added that account to IIS_WPG?
5. Compare the Permissions on this VDIR vs. the one that works
6. Finally, what URL are you using?  If its not the machine name, could Kerberos be the issue?  Have you set your SPNs correctly?  Have you turned off Negotiate?